# Getting started with the robot_navigation stack

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently the `dwb_local_planner` was suggested to me ([here](https://answers.ros.org/question/356895/dwa-local-planner-deceleration-limit/?answer=356939#post-id-356939)) as a replacement for the `dwa_local_planner`since it allows for much better configuration.

So I read about the [robot_navigation stack](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation) and watched a [talk](https://vimeo.com/236487972) by Dr. David V Lu on the benefits of using the `dwb_local_planner`.

I'm very intrigued to give the whole `robot_nagivation` stack a try (locomotor, dlux_global_planner, dwb_local_planner) but so far I haven't found any good getting started guide. The best I could find is a [doc](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/tree/master/nav_core_adapter) for the `nav_core_adapter` which is an adapter for backwards compatibility for people who want to convert their move_base/dwa_local_planner configuration to work with `robot_navigation`.

Since I'm fine with configuring the `robot_nagivation` stack from scratch I don't think I need to use the `nav_core_adapter`.

What's the best way to get started on locomotor, dlux_global_planner, dwb_local_planner? Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357516/getting-started-with-the-robot_navigation-stack/) by [dschnabel](https://answers.ros.org/users/51661/dschnabel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2020-07-18

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a shame that there's so little documentation for the robot_navigation stack because it's a great implementation of the navigation stack. The code is written cleanly, it has meaningful comments and can be easily extended with personal modifications.

After spending a few months diving into the code and intricacies of `locomotor`, `dwb_local_planner` and `dwb_critics` and painfully extracting config options, I came up with a navigation stack that works fairly well for my robot.

For everyone interested, here's the launch file I'm using:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="prefix" default="" />
  <node name="locomotor" pkg="locomotor" type="locomotor1" output="screen" launch-prefix="$(arg prefix)">
    <rosparam file="$(find locomotor)/launch/rovy.yaml" command="load"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

And for config options (this is a very explicit version, I'm sure much can be optimized):

```
controller_frequency: 10.0
global_plan_topic: global_plan
global_plan_type: Path3D
global_plan_epsilon: -1.0
twist_topic: cmd_vel
twist_type: Twist3D

global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  rolling_window: false
  track_unknown_space: true
  always_send_full_costmap: false
  footprint_topic: "footprint"
  width: 15
  height: 15
  origin_x: -7.5
  origin_y: -7.5
  resolution: 0.07
  update_frequency: 2.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0

  footprint: [[0.11,0.15],[0.11,-0.15],[-0.27,-0.15],[-0.27,0.15]]
  footprint_padding: 0.02

  static_layer:
    map_topic: map
    first_map_only: true
    subscribe_to_updates: false
    use_maximum: false
    lethal_cost_threshold: 100
    unknown_cost_value: -1
    trinary_costmap: true

  obstacle_layer:
    transform_tolerance: 0.2
    observation_sources: scan_sensor
    scan_sensor: {
      topic: scan,
      sensor_frame: d435_link,
      observation_persistence: 0.0,
      expected_update_rate: 0.0,
      data_type: LaserScan,
      min_obstacle_height: -10.0,
      max_obstacle_height: 10.0,
      inf_is_valid: true,
      clearing: true,
      marking: true
    }
    obstacle_range: 1.5
    raytrace_range: 2.0

  inflation_layer:
    cost_scaling_factor: 15.0
    inflation_radius: 2.0
    inflate_unknown: false

  plugins:
   - {name: static_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
   - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
   - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

local_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  track_unknown_space: false
  always_send_full_costmap: true
  footprint_topic: "footprint"
  width: 3
  height: 3
  origin_x: -1.5
  origin_y: -1.5
  resolution: 0.02
  update_frequency: 10.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0
  rolling_window: true

  footprint: [[0.11,0.15],[0.11,-0.15],[-0.27,-0.15],[-0.27,0.15]]
  footprint_padding: 0.02

  obstacle_layer:
    transform_tolerance: 0.2
    observation_sources: scan_sensor
    scan_sensor: {
      topic: scan,
      sensor_frame: d435_link,
      observation_persistence: 0.0,
      expected_update_rate: 0.0,
      data_type: LaserScan,
      min_obstacle_height: -10.0,
      max_obstacle_height: 10.0,
      inf_is_valid: false,
      clearing: true,
      marking: true
    }
    obstacle_range: 1.5
    raytrace_range: 2.0

  inflation_layer:
    cost_scaling_factor: 15.0
    inflation_radius: 2.0
    inflate_unknown: false

  plugins:
   - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
   - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

DluxGlobalPlanner:
  neutral_cost: 50
  scale: 3.0
  unknown_interpretation: lethal
  path_caching: false
  improvement_threshold: -1.0
  publish_potential: false
  print_statistics: false
  potential_calculator: dlux_plugins::AStar
  traceback: dlux_plugins::GradientPath

  # AStar
  manhattan_heuristic: false
  use_kernel: true
  minimum_requeue_change: 1.0

  # GradientPath
  step_size: 0.5
  lethal_cost: 250.0
  iteration_factor: 4.0
  grid_step_near_high: false

DWBLocalPlanner:
  update_costmap_before_planning: true
  prune_plan: true
  prune_distance: 1.0
  short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: true
  debug_trajectory_details: false
#  publish_cost_grid_pc: true

  trajectory_generator_name: dwb_plugins::LimitedAccelGenerator
  # velocities
  min_vel_x: -0.4
  max_vel_x: 0.4
  min_vel_y: 0.0
  max_vel_y: 0.0
  max_vel_theta: 2.0
  # acceleration
  acc_lim_x: 1.2
  acc_lim_y: 0.0
  acc_lim_theta: 8.731380878
  # deceleration
  decel_lim_x: -1.2
  decel_lim_y: 0.0
  decel_lim_theta: -10.948097518
  # absolute speeds (in either direction)
  min_speed_xy: 0.1
  max_speed_xy: 0.4
  min_speed_theta: 0.3

  goal_checker_name: dwb_plugins::SimpleGoalChecker
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.1
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.07

  critics:
  - PathDragging
  - PreferForward
  - RotateToGoal
  - RotateToStart
  - Oscillation
  - Recovery

  # PathDragging critic
  PathDragging:
   scale: 1.0

  # PreferForward critic
  PreferForward:
    backward_cost: 1.0
    forward_cost: 0.0
    scale: 1.0

  # RotateToGoal critic
  RotateToGoal:
    xy_goal_tolerance: 0.1
    trans_stopped_velocity: 0.1
    slowing_factor: 5.0
    lookahead_time: -1.0
    scale: 1.0

  # RotateToStart critic
  RotateToStart:
    scale: 1.0

  # Oscillation critic
  Oscillation:
    x_only_threshold: 0.05
    oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
    oscillation_reset_angle: 0.2
    oscillation_reset_time: -1.0
    scale: 1.0

  # Recovery critic
  Recovery:
    scale: 1.0
```

Those familiar with `dwb_ciritcs` will recognize three new critics: `PathDragging`, `RotateToStart`, and `Recovery`. I wrote those myself as I couldn't get proper behavior with the default ones. Especially the `PathDragging` critic improved navigation greatly for me and it even made four other default critics redundant: GoalDistCritic, PathDistCritic, GoalAlignCritic, and PathAlignCritic.

I also made direct changes to `dwb_local_planner` to force a recalculation of the global plan if any obstacle is detected on or close the global path.

For anyone interested, my modifications can be found under https://github.com/dschnabel/robot_navigation (branch 'rovy'). Please note that this is a highly customized codebase and probably wouldn't compile/work for you out-of-the-box. I would have to pretty it up and make it work for the public which requires some work. I'm not sure how much interest there is, so I'm being pragmatic and leaving it as is for now ;)

---

Originally posted by [dschnabel](https://answers.ros.org/users/51661/dschnabel/) with karma: 103 on 2020-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3